# javascript arrays relating/corresponding to each other

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have two arrays, one with strings of large numbers and the other with the sums of the large numbers added together, is there any way where I can have the two arrays correspond with each other? Like to make location [2] in the first array correspond with the same location in the second array. More specifically, I originally establish the array of large numbers, and I've written a function that creates the second array giving me the sums of each numeral in the large numbers (ex. 123456789 in the first array would be 45 in the second array), but I need to be able to link the two arrays because the first array needs to work with any number of strings of numbers. (sorry if this is confusing; I'm just a little out of my depth on this.)

Here is the code I'm working on:

```
var theArray = ["585-777-7279", "922-901-8934", "112-211-4857", "994-934-9989"];

var plsWork = function() {
    var theArrayTwo = theArray.join().replace(/-/g, "");
    var theArrayThree = theArrayTwo.split(",").map(Number);
    var phoneSum = theArrayThree.map(function (a) {
        return Array.prototype.slice.call(a.toString()).map(Number).reduce(function(b,c) {
            return b + c;
        });
    })
    phoneSum.sort().reverse();

    console.log(phoneSum);
};
```

Basically, I just want to know if there's a way that I can get the two arrays (the original and the one created in the function) to correspond. Ideally, I would like to be able to have it where I can show that the smallest sum corresponds with the number from the first array.

Comment: please add some data, like the arrays, you are talking about.

Comment: if they have the same index, it should be fine.. otherwise create an array of objects.. `[{num:123, sum:6 }, {}...]` and keep in one place

Comment: need to include a code snippet or at least some json

Answer (score 0):

If you already have the two arrays, the best way to relate one to another would be to create an array of objects as suggested by @webdeb.

If instead you have the array of large numbers and then all you want is to create a second array that in each index contains the sum of all the digits of the number in the first array, than I would use the following code:

```
var large_numbers = [1234, 2345, 3456];

function sumDigits(number) {
  var digitsArray = [],
        string = number.toString(); // convert number to string

  for (let i = 0; i < string.length; i++) {
    // push the numbers to a temporary array so that 
    // I can sum them one by one later
    digitsArray.push(parseInt(string[i], 10));
  }

  // return the sum of all the elements of the digitsArray
  return tempArray.reduce(function(prev, curr) {
    return prev + curr;
  })
}

var sumsArray = large_numbers.map(sumDigits); // -> [10, 14, 18]
```

The sumsArray contains in the sum of all the digits of the number in the large numbers array in the same index.